# Создание "Избранные товары (wishlist)" в интернет магазине

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress

Здравствуйте! Делаю интернет магазин на WordPress, и в нем необходимо реализовать добавление товаров в список избранных. Т.к. использую нестандартную тему не смог найти работающий плагин. Решил сделать сам. Список товаров должен хранится только в куках. Как это можно реализовать? Может есть какие-то примеры?

Comment: Непонятно, как функционал плагина связан с темой, но OK. Если реализовывать самому, то: 1) создаете в php при отображении товара в архиве или на странице товара кнопку "В избранное" с id товара в data, 2) Пишете js - по клику считываете id из data, 3) заносите в куки через js, 4) обновляете область вывода избранных товаров с помощью ajax.

Comment: В общем, покажите свой код и что у вас конкретно не получается.

Comment: Есть рабочие плагины не работают с "нестандартной" темой - это первый и серьёзный звоночек, что с темой есть проблемы. Нужно стандартизировать тему а не плодить ещё большие костыли.

Comment: @KAGG Design, а не подскажите как хранить в куки? Я так понимаю массивом. Как при этом добавлять новый элемент или удалять из этого массива? Как проверять наличие элемента в массиве?

Comment: Почитайте про куки: https://learn.javascript.ru/cookie Хранить надо сериализованным массивом, конечно. Читать и обновлять полностью массив.

Comment: @KAGG Design, а есть разница чем обрабатывать? js или php+ajax?

Comment: ajax = js + php. А обрабатывать так, как я написал. На каждом шаге свои инструменты.